# How to reach better accuracy in Object Matching?

Tags: java, c++, opencv, javacv

I use 2 OpenCV Matching functions to match 2 Objects in 2 different Images ..
first that's i use it's BFMatcher the second it's DescriptorMatcher,
My code work well but accuracy it's about 50% ..
So My Question it's how can i reach 90% accuracy ?

Here is a matching part of my code :

```
"   System.out.println("\nMatching..");
        Mat res = new Mat();
        KeyPoint keyPoints = new KeyPoint();
        detector.detect(input, keyPoints);
        extractor.compute(input, keyPoints, res);
        Map<String, Double> m = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        BFMatcher _matcher = new BFMatcher(opencv_core.NORM_L2, true);
        DescriptorMatcher dmatcher = new BFMatcher();

        //DMatch matches = null;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Mat> item : mdescs.entrySet()) {
            Mat t = new Mat(item.getValue());
            DMatch matches = new DMatch();
            DMatchVectorVector dmatches = new DMatchVectorVector();
            //DMatch kmatches = new DMatch();
            if (ratio) {
                dmatcher.knnMatch(res, t, dmatches, 2);
                double i1 = getRatio(dmatches);
                dmatches = new DMatchVectorVector();
                dmatcher.knnMatch(t, res, dmatches, 2);
                double i2 = getRatio(dmatches);
                /*+ "ratio" + Integer.valueOf(i1 > i2 ? i1 : i2)*/
                m.put(item.getKey(), (i1 > i2 ? i1 : i2)/*Double.valueOf(dmatches.size())*/);

            } else {
                _matcher.match(res, t, matches);
                m.put(item.getKey(), Double.valueOf(matches.capacity()));
            }
            System.out.print(".");"
```

Thanks.

Comment: would you share some samples of your objects, images .?

Comment: @dervish my objects samples are logos like cocacola, mcdonalds, android etc ..

Comment: I suggest you to apply as well, the cascade detector of opencv. let me know if you are not familiar with it.

Comment: As well, would please define your accuracy term? what's your test case, measures ????

Comment: @dervish Thank you for your response, i think the cascade detector it's only for face Recognition how can i use it for Object Recognition ?, my accuracy term it's to reach 90%, my test case it's with 40-50 descriptors with different logos like CocaCola, starbucks etc, and i compare them with 5-6 test descriptors to now i have 3-4/5-6 right matches. Thanks.

Comment: you can use cascade to detect any abject you want. Just train it before use it, then use the generated xml file. here is tutorial of how training : http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html?highlight=train%20cascade%20classifier

Comment: @dervish, OK thank you for the tutorial will implement it and tell you results ..